# My java program Compiles but it doesnt run because it cannot find or load the main class file

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program which checks if symbols such as {}, [], () are placed correctly in a String. My problem is I've managed to make the program compile but when I try run it, it gives me the following error:
Error: Could not find or load main class P.java
I'm not really sure what is going wrong as I've only been programming for about two months. Any help at all in the matter would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class P {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char[] opening = { '(', '{', '[' };
        char[] closing = { ')', '}', ']' };
        String mark;
        char marks;
        Scanner terminalInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        Stack<String> myStack = new Stack<>();
        String sentence = terminalInput.nextLine();
        char[] letters = sentence.toCharArray();

        boolean yes = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
            for (int a = 0; a < 6; a++) {
                if (letters[i] == opening[a]) {
                    mark = Character.toString(opening[a]);
                    myStack.push(mark);
                }

                if (letters[i] == closing[a]) {
                    mark = myStack.peek();
                    marks = mark.charAt(0);
                    if (marks != opening[a]) {
                        yes = false;
                        System.out.println(yes);

                    } else
                        myStack.pop();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(yes);
    }
}
```

Comment: try running `java P -cp .`. What does it say?

Comment: Same message, Could not find or load main class P

Comment: is there a `.class` file in the current directory?

Comment: Yeah, it updates every time i compile it

Comment: Could it be possible its just the stack class?

Comment: Are you using an IDE? if so, What IDE are you using?

Comment: No, I used a code writer app on windows 8.1 and compiled it using command prompt

Answer (score 4):

"P.java" is the name of the source code file. The name of the class is just `P`, so that's what you should use when trying to run:

```
java P
```

Comment: Thanks but when I try Java P I get the same error message, "Could not find or load main class P"

Comment: That's a different error, caused by a different problem. It's possible that you have the CLASSPATH  environment variable set, interfering with how classes are loaded. If the class was successfully compiled and you're in the right directory, `java -classpath . P` should work even if CLASSPATH is set.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem while running my program on the command prompt in Windows. Turns out, the CLASSPATH should not contain spaces. My CLASSPATH was initially C:\MyFolder\Java progs. It would compile on executing:

> javac helloworld.java

But the class file wouldn't get created, even though my CLASSPATH Environment Variable was set to C:\MyFolder\Java progs. As soon as I changed the name of the folder to "Javaprogs", it started working smoothly. The .class file was created and

> java helloworld

worked successfully. Hope this helps.